# ayuda con un for de javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Buen día, estoy intentando que al poner un valor en un input normal de cantidad, clickear en un botón y me salga el numero de campos que dice en cantidad.

Lo estoy haciendo de esta forma pero solo me salen 2 campos así yo ponga 4.

```
var cantidad = document.getElementsByName("cant");
function agregarDetalle(idseriales,serial){
for (var i = 0; i <=cantidad.length; i++) {
var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="serial[]" value="" id="serial[]"></input></td>'+
        '<td><button  type="button" id="agregarArt" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="agregarDetalle()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button><td>'+
        '<td><input type="hidden" name="idseriales[]" id="idseriales[]" value="'+idseriales+'"></input></td>'+

        '</tr>';

        cont++;
        detalles=detalles+1;
        $('#detalles').append(fila); 
    }
}
```

agradeceria sus comentarios ya que no se como hacer para que me tome el valor que le pongo en el input

Answer (score 0):

Es que no estas tomando el valor del campo y estas haciendo el for por la longitud del campo cuando deberia ser por el valor. Con la función addFila le puedo enviar un objeto con las propiedades que desee utilizar.

```js
$("#add").on("click", function(){
  $("#detalles").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i <= $("#cant").val() - 1; i++) {
    addFila({
      fila: i
    });
  }
});

function addFila(row) {
    var newFila = `<tr class="filas" id="fila${row.fila}">` +
      `<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
            onclick="eliminarDetalle(${row.fila})">X</button></td>` +
      `<td><input type="text" id="serial${row.fila}" 
            value="serial${row.fila}"></input></td>` +
      `<td><button type="button" id="agregarArt" class="btn btn-primary"
            onclick="agregarDetalle()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button><td>` +
      `<td><input type="hidden" id="idseriales${row.fila}" 
            value="idseriales${row.fila}"></input></td>`+
    `</tr>`;
    $('#detalles').append(newFila);
};

//COMENTE TU CODIGO PARA HACER UNA PRUEBA

/*var cantidad = document.getElementsByName("cant")[0].value;
function agregarDetalle(idseriales,serial){
for (var i = 0; i <=cantidad; i++) {
var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="serial[]" value="" id="serial[]"></input></td>'+
        '<td><button  type="button" id="agregarArt" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="agregarDetalle()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button><td>'+
        '<td><input type="hidden" name="idseriales[]" id="idseriales[]" value="'+idseriales+'"></input></td>'+

        '</tr>';

        cont++;
        detalles=detalles+1;
        $('#detalles').append(fila); 
    }
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="cant">
<input type="button" id="add" value="Agregar Filas">
<table id="detalles"></table>
```

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, lo hice tal cual dice pero ahora solo me agrega de a 1

Comment: haz un console log a la variable cantidad para ver si es problema al traer la variable o si es problema de ver como estás insertando las filas

Comment: Prueba con esa solución que te estoy presentando, lo hace de una manera dinámica y mas entendible. No se porque estas asignando esto name="idseriales[]" id="idseriales[]" y name="serial[]" id="serial[]" al final simplemente asignaras el mismo id y name para todas las filas.

Comment: victor perdomo. muchas gracias me a funcionado el codigo que me has enviado y sirve perfecto, lo tengo asi name="idseriales[]" id="idseriales[]" y name="serial[]" id="serial[]" porque a la hora de guardar el tiene que identificar que es un arreglo, y sin eso solo me guarda un el primer registro. pero ya lo solucione y quedo perfecto. gracias

Comment: De nada hermano éxitos con tu proyecto, recuerda validar la pregunta como buena para que otro usuario con la misma duda pueda utilizarla.